# Оцените мой алгоритм шифрования

Tags: шифрование

Здравствуйте! Я студент, готовлюсь к одному конкурсу по программированию. Для него я подготовил программу для android - мастер паролей. Я разработал свой алгоритм шифрования паролей. Это простой шифр Цезаря, но ключ от него извлекается из пароля от хранилища (из его длины), который зашифрован в md5. Идея в простом алгоритме шифрования, ключ от которого никак нельзя получить злоумышленнику, т.к. он не хранится.

Но при таком раскладе злоумышленник мог бы подобрать ключ из всего лишь 255 вариантов (255 - длина строки со всеми символами в шифре Цезаря), но это число можно увеличить до 255 в степени n, где n - длина символов пароля, который нужно зашифровать, если подбирать отдельный ключ для каждого символа в этом пароле. При этом нужно добывать эти ключи также из главного пароля, но при этом мы не можем использовать две переменные дважды (переменные - то есть способы получения числа из этого пароля. Например длина пароля и кол-во самых часто-повторяющихся символов в нем), т.к. они будут вытикать из предыдущих подборов.

Что вы думаете об этом алгоритме? Насколько он надежен? Как подобрать n ключей? Как еще его улучшить?
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Хотите реального шифрования - используйте AES. Шифр Цезаря (с любым ключом) обладает практически нулевой криптостойкостью

Comment: я несколько раз попробовал понять ваш алгоритм, но у меня не получилось. но в любом случае шифр Цезаря плохой выбор.

Comment: Я тоже мало что понял, но выглядит ненадёжно

Comment: В ascii таблице из 256 символов в паролях люди используют в основном латинские буквы, цифры и изредка знаки. таким образом более половины таблицы в паролях использоваться не могут. При переборе ключей для цезаря мы сможем сходу отбросить те, что приводят нас в неиспользуемую область таблицы, это минимум половина всех вариантов. после чего берем даже предположим 128 подходящих вариантов (скорее меньше) и пробуем их к ресурсу для которого пароль. при желании можно даже в ручную подобрать.